# How do while(!kbhit()) COBOL Equivalent?

Tags: cobol

I want to detect a key press event in COBOL, using isCOBOL compiler. How to do that?

EX in C:

`if(time==despert_time){
    while(!kbhit()){ 
        Beep(500,500);
    }
}`

Comment: Presumably you have a manual?

Comment: Because COBOL was originally designed without much means to interact with humans, compiler vendors have augmented, with their own extensions, the simple DISPLAY and ACCEPT that are available. You need to find out *if* and *how* isCOBOL allows you to do that. The `do` is a simple in-line `PERFORM`.

Comment: GUI or not GUI?  From console you might be able to get away with calling into Java System.in.Available() (if the terminal is not buffering on lines).  If there are graphics involved, write up a tiny class to add an ActionListener and a handler for keyPressed, keyReleased, or keyTyped (depending on how you want to handle it).  In short, this will likely be easier from Java than COBOL.  If you really need to do this from COBOL, look to `CALL "SYSTEM" using "stty raw"`,  then `"stty cooked"` after you've accepted a keypress (on GNU/Linux).  Windows console will have a different sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to get a user interaction from console.
If it isn't happening within a time frame: beep

```
PERFORM FOREVER *> or UNTIL EXIT or UNTIL 0 = 1, depending on the available extensions
   ACCEPT OMITTED *> or ACCEPT DUMMY [which you'd define as 77 DUMMY PIC X.], depending on the available extensions
      BEFORE TIME 500 *> [or WITH TIMEOUT 500] this is a more or less common extension, with most vendors using a different time scale --> may need to change the 500
   END-ACCEPT
   IF keypressed NOT = timeout *> the actual var to be checked and the timeout value need to be checked in the docs
      EXIT PERFORM
   END-IF
   CALL x'E5'
      ON EXCEPTION *> the system call x'E5' for beep may not be available
         DISPLAY SPACE AT 2080 WITH BEEP *> may not be available, too...
   END-CALL
END-PERFORM
```

Check the online documentation that ships with your compiler (it is "available for clients only", therefore we can not check).

Comment: Done, sorry for the late answer haha